# How one can choose some pratial sums to verify the inequality: $S_1≥S_2+a+ b×S_3+ c×S_4$

Tags: inequality, summation

Let $0<a<1,b>1,c>1$ be some real numbers. Let $S$ denotes the sum of all the terms $d^{j},j=0,..,m$, where $d≥3$. Define $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ be the partial sums of the terms $d^{j},j=0,..,m$ such that the union of all these sums is equal to $S$. Here partial sum means any sum of $h$ terms and not necessary conssecutive.

Then my **question** is: How one can choose those four sums to verify the inequality:
$$S_1≥S_2+a+ b×S_3+ c×S_4$$

Comment: Can you please tell me what are partial sums? Is it like sum of n terms from the beginning?

Comment: @Gwen: partial sums are sums of $h$ terms and $h<m+1$

Comment: @Gwen: It is  not necessary form the begining.

Comment: Also please can you tell how is $S_1$ different from $S_2$? Say I take $S_1$ as $d²+d³+d⁴$ and $S_2$ as $d⁵+d⁶$. Is this valid?

Comment: @Gwen: Any choice that verifying the inequality is valid.